# Codekit and Zurb Foundation errors

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

Running a compass and zurb foundation project. When I use `compass watch` to compile the project, it works great. When I use codekit, I can't get it to compile.

The first error I get is:

```
error app.scss (Line 24 of _block-grid.scss: -0.625em*px isn't a valid CSS value.)
```

So I hunted down that line in _block-grid.scss on zurbs github and saw it was referencing `$block-grid-default-spacing`. If I uncomment the value `$block-grid-default-spacing: emCalc(20);` in my settings file, it works fine, onto the next error:

```
error app.scss (Line 111 of _type.scss: Incompatible units: 'px' and ''.)
```

I have everything installed properly. I am pointing codekit to my local versions of SASS and Compass and I'm still getting errors. Any idea what I can do?

If I do not include my `settings.scss` file, everything compiles correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch CodeKit to use an external Compass compiler in order to use compass plugins like Zurb.

If you're using RVM, first run the system command on it. Then, install Compass and Zurb at the command line. Then go into CodeKit's preferences and select Compass in the Languages tab. Use the Advanced Compiler Settings area to switch the app to your external compass compiler.

Comment: Read above: "I am pointing codekit to my local versions of SASS and Compass"